# From running javascript in VSCode, invoke a configured task from `tasks.json`

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In VSCode, I am running the script 'control.js' in `Node.js`. I now want to run (called from a line in `control.js`) a task in `tasks.json` of the project folder, selecting that task using the `label` property.

From information I have found, I am directed toward using `exec()` or `execSync()`, within `child_process` to run an instance of 'code'.

The functions suggested are producing errors, like so:

```js
// taskLabel is the `label` property of the wanted task defined 
// in tasks.json of the project (folder)
execSync(`code --task ${taskLabel}`);  
     // error: no option `task` is known for 'code'

execSync(`npx -p vscode@latest vscode --executeTask "${taskLabel}"`) 
    // error: 'vscode' is not a recognized command
```

---

@starball : The configured tasks of interest in the project `tasks.json` are essentially to run the TypeScript compiler (`tsc`) with different `tsconfig.json` files (one for a "full" build, another with a shorter-in-time "test" build). Based on suggestion of @rioV8, I can work around calling an instance of VS Code to run TSC to do that task and to achieve that same effect. So I open the `json` file and parse it to find the contained object with the `label` property I want. For tasks of `"type": "typescript"`, there is no `command` property, but the task is still understood.  There might be other use cases where several commands in a certain order must be done to ensure that the result that VS Code would provide by telling it "open the 'tasks.json' and run this task with this 'label'", and the developer needs to figure this out.

Comment: why not read `tasks.json`, extract the wanted task, and execute the command

Comment: that's awfully heavy to run a task. what does the task do?